# regex properly dealing with nested patterns

Tags: regex, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to find the best approach to deal with an issue I have. I need to be able to extract comments from strings, which are patterned as being a content between brackets on the end of the string. The comment can be a single one, multiple ones, nested ones or combinations of these.

Some examples :

```
this is a string (with comment)
this is another string (with comment)(and more comment)
this is yet another string (with comment (and some nested comment)
```

That's the most easy format, fairly easy to separate using the following regex (access VBA)

```
regex.Pattern = "^([^(]*)(\(.*\))+$"
```

I get the following correct output, where group1 is the value, and group2 would be the comment

```
group1: this is a string / group2: (with comment)
group1: this is another string / group2:  (with comment)(and more comment)
group1: this is yet another string / group2:  (with comment (and some nested comment)
```

The problem is that in some cases I have arrays, and these should fail. The arrays can either be defined by a comma or by a slash. Pretty straightforward, but the problem is that these tokens can also be used for other purposes. So if a comma or slash is found in the string it's considered an array, unless :

```
- the token is within the comment
- the slash is part of a fractional number
```

some examples :

```
this is string1 with a fractional 1/4 number (with comment)
this is string1 (with a fractional 1/4 in comment)
this is string1 (with comment1) / this is string2 (with comment2)
this is string1 (with some data, seperated by a comma) , this is string2 (with comment3 / comment4)
this is string1 (with a fractional 1/4) / this is string2 (with comment2,comment3)
```

added examples : first one should fail as it contains an array token (the slash) which is not part of a fractional number. The second one selects too much, as it only should take the last comment instead of the whole string from first to second comment.

```
this is string1 without comment / this is string2 (with comment2)
This is a  string (with subcomment) where only the last should be selected (so this one)
```

How would I adjust the logic the best so that it fails on repetitions unless the comma or slash is part of the exceptions ? I end up with monstercode so would like to see if there are easier options available. So above exceptions should end up as follows :

```
ex1 / group1 : this is string1 with a fractional 1/4 number group2: (with comment)
ex2 / group1 : this is string1 group2 : (with a fractional 1/4 in comment)
ex3 to 5 should fail as they are considered arrays and need some additional logic
```

Hope it's a bit clear..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this,

```
^((?:(?!\)\s*[,\/]).)*?)(\([^()]*\))$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aW3pR4/7)

**Update:**

```
^(?=(?:(?!\)\s*[,\/]|\s\/\s).)*$)(.*?)((?:\([^()\n]*\))+)$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aW3pR4/24)

Comment: pretty close, great ! It's not matching fully anymore now on the 'simpler ones' as [this is another string (with comment)(and more comment)] but I'll give it a try from here

Comment: What would be the output for the above input?

Comment: first group should be [this is another string] , second group should be the comments [(with comment)(and more comment)], so any repetition of bracketed data.

Comment: sorry, I was too fast by accepting the answer but it remains valuable of course. The answer only works when both sites of the array contain a comment which means it's too wide. The conditions are not really met, so as soon as a comma or slash appears outside of a note (brackets) , or is not part of a fraction, the condition will have to be negative

Comment: Hi Raj, I added 2 more examples that explain the issue

Comment: you're my hero for the day :-)